# Strange behaviour after deleting search result object in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a table view with sections populated by core data. I have implemented a search bar, but I am having some problems with it. To test it I have created 3 core data objects:

```
1. item 2(overdue)-> OVERDUE section
2. item 1(today)-> TODAY section
3. item 3(upcoming)->UPCOMING section.
```

With the help of other SO, more expert users than me, I have solved some of the first issues with the search bar implementation. One of them was to have the search results objects under a new section, SEARCH  RESULTS (# objects), which is working as expected. 
The next issue I want to solve is following:
- Once the search is finished, the result objects are shown under the new section SEARCH RESULTS, but a not desired behaviour is shown when trying to delete the object, as deleting normal objects, I swipe the row from right to left and appears the red DELETE button, if I tap on the button, the normal behaviour should be: 
1. The row moves automatically to the right again.
2. The table is reloaded, and the deleted row doesn't appear again.

In this case, when deleting the result object row, after tapping the delete button, the row remains swiped to the left, no further action is possible except tapping on the cancel button. Then the table view appears again in its normal view. The deleted result object row is certainly deleted.
This is my code, any help to solved this issue is very welcomed:

```
#import "ToDoItemsTableViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"
#import "ToDoSubItemsTableViewController.h"

@interface ToDoItemsTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation ToDoItemsTableViewController
@synthesize searchResults;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    return [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //navigation bar background image
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar

     setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"]

     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIColor blackColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [UIColor blackColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,nil];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;



    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
        abort();
    }
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.searchResults = nil;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"addToDoItem"]){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        AddToDoItemViewController *addToDoItemViewController = (AddToDoItemViewController*)navigationController.topViewController;
        ToDoItem *addToDoItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        addToDoItem.todoDueDate = [NSDate date];
        addToDoItemViewController.addToDoItem = addToDoItem;
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toToDoSubItems"]){

        ToDoSubItemsTableViewController *todoSubItemsTableViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ToDoItem *selectedToDoItem = (ToDoItem*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        todoSubItemsTableViewController.selectedToDoItem = selectedToDoItem;



    }




}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else {
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    ToDoItem *toDoItem = nil;



    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        }
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        toDoItem = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.todoName;



        NSDate *fechaToDO = toDoItem.todoDueDate;

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
        NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];



        cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;

    }
    else
    {


    ToDoItem *todoItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = todoItem.todoName;



    NSDate *fechaToDO = todoItem.todoDueDate;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
    NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];



    cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *header = @"customHeader";

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *vHeader;

    vHeader = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:header];

    if (!vHeader) {
        vHeader = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:header];
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    if (section == 0) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    else if (section == 1) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else if (section == 2) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }


    vHeader.textLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    return vHeader;
}
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S E A R C H   R E S U L T S (%d)",[self.searchResults count]];
        return valor;
    }
    else {


    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    NSString *sectionname = [theSection name];

    if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"0"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"O V E R D U E   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                                             numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"1"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"T O D A Y   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                           numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"2"]){

        NSString *valor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"U P C O M I N G   (%d)", [self.tableView
                                                             numberOfRowsInSection:section]];
        return valor;
    }




    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count]>0){
        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo name];
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }
    }

}


#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Section

-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController{

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil){
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoDueDate" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor1, nil];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}


#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Delegates

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}

-(void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:{

            ToDoItem *changeToDoItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.textLabel.text = changeToDoItem.todoName;
            NSDate *fechaToDO = changeToDoItem.todoDueDate;

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
            NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;
        }
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }


}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type{

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }

}





/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        ToDoItem *ToDoItemToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [context deleteObject:ToDoItemToDelete];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        }

    }
}



/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Content Filtering

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    self.searchResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        ToDoItem * item = evaluatedObject;
        NSString* name = item.todoName;

        //searchText having length < 3 should not be considered
        if (!!searchText && [searchText length] < 3) {
            return YES;
        }

        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [name isEqualToString:scope])  {
            return ([name rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
        }
        return NO; //if nothing matches
    }]];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
       ...
        [context deleteObject:ToDoItemToDelete];

  [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

.....
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        }

    }
}
```

You should delete you row inside this method.

Comment: Thank you, but there are two possible data sources, the normal fetch result objects and the search result objects. The code from this method, as it is now, is used to delete the row from the fetched result object. Do you mean adding there also the code to delete the search result object? If yes, please tell me how...